# Effective way to put case condition to find the correct value in SQL Server from multiple rows on database table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need little help to simply the data which has multiple **distinct** rows with different values.

I need to apply a `CASE` condition based on the different values in order to extract the correct **single dataset** row.

The sample core table name: `Employee`

```
ID EmployeeCode DEPT_Code
--------------------------
1  123          X
1  123          X1
1  123          X2
```

On `DEPT_code` I want to apply **CASE** condition to produce the output in one row

- if at least one of the multiple `Dept_code` has 'X' then `value = 'ABC'`
- if the multiple `Dept_code` has 'X1' and 'X2', then `value = 'ABC'`
- if the multiple `Dept_code` has just 'X1' only, then `value = 'xyz'`
- if the multiple `Dept_code` has just 'X2' only, then `value = 'opq'`

The output will be in single row.

```
 ID   EmployeeCode   Dept_Code
 ----------------------------------------------------
 1     123           (Value based on a CASE expression)
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You haven't shown much research here, or in various prior questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ID, EmployeeCode,
    case
        when max(Dept_Code) = 'x2' then 3
        when max(Dept_Code) = 'x1' and count(*) = 1 then 2
        when max(Dept_Code) = 'x1' and min(Dept_Code) = 'x' then 1
        else 0
    end
from employee
group by ID, EmployeeCode
```

There are all kinds of variations on this that get the same results. Since you didn't explain what the different combinations mean you have to decide how to set up the logic according to your data.

Comment: Thank you @shawnt00 !.
in my request i did minor mistake in the 2nd condition.  It should be as follows:
if at least one of the multiple Dept_code has 'X' then value = 'ABC'
if the multiple Dept_code has 'X1' and 'X2', then value = 'ABC'
if the multiple Dept_code has just 'X1' only, then value = 'xyz'
if the multiple Dept_code has just 'X2' only, then value = 'opq'

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

**untested**

```
select e.ID, e.EmployeeCode
   -- each of C1, C2, C3 DEPT_Code will be null if the condition is not met.
   -- nested isnull statements select whichever condition is met first.
   ,isnull(max(C1.DEPT_Code), isnull(max(C2.DEPT_Code), isnull(max(C3.DEPT_Code), 'unknown'))) DEPT_Code
from Employee e
left outer join (  -- IDs that match your first or second condition, which are the same.
   select e1.ID, 'ABC' Dept_Code
   from Employee e1
   where DEPT_Code = 'X'
   group by e1.ID
) C1 on C1.ID = e.ID
left outer join ( -- IDs that match your third condition
   select e2.ID, 'xyz' Dept_Code
   from Employee e2
   group by e2.ID
   having min(e2.Dept_Code) = 'X1'
      and max(e2.Dept_Code) = 'X1'
) C2 on C2.ID = e.ID
left outer join ( -- IDs that match your fourth condition
   select e3.ID, 'opq' Dept_Code
   from Employee e3
   group by e3.ID
   having min(e3.Dept_Code) = 'X2'
      and max(e3.Dept_Code) = 'X2'
) C3 on C3.ID = e.ID
group by e.ID, e.EmployeeCode
order by e.ID
```

Comment: Thank you @avery_larry!. 
In my request i did minor mistake in the 2nd condition. It should be as follows: if at least one of the multiple Dept_code has 'X' then value = 'ABC' if the multiple Dept_code has 'X1' and 'X2', then value = 'ABC' if the multiple Dept_code has just 'X1' only, then value = 'xyz' if the multiple Dept_code has just 'X2' only, then value = 'opq